# Pyautogui function LocateOnScreen is giving error despite having installed required library(using python3 on ubuntu).Please help me out

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyautogui

The function used in interpreter:

```py
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('zoom_pic.png')
```

THE ERROR IS:-

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
   pyautogui.locateOnScreen('zoom_pic.png')
 File "/home/aaryan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
   return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/aaryan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
   return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/aaryan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 371, in locateOnScreen
   screenshotIm = screenshot(region=None) # the locateAll() function must handle cropping to return accurate coordinates, so don't pass a region here.
 File "/home/aaryan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 498, in _screenshot_linux
   raise NotImplementedError('"scrot" must be installed to use screenshot functions in Linux. Run: sudo apt-get install scrot')
NotImplementedError: "scrot" must be installed to use screenshot functions in Linux. Run: sudo apt-get install scrot
```

Answer (score 1):

The error messsage says:

```
"scrot" must be installed to use screenshot functions in Linux. Run: sudo apt-get install scrot
```

Have you tried `sudo apt-get install scrot` in your terminal? This should allow you to run functions like `pyautogui.locateOnScreen()` and `pyautogui.screenshot()`.

Comment: Yes I have, despite that it is giving error.

Comment: Maybe you should try reinstalling pyautogui or installing a different version. Maybe something was wrong with your original install.

Comment: I did the installation of "scrot" again and it worked this time.